# Reading csv and problem with float values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, read.csv

I am reading a csv as follows:

```
info_prets= pd.read_csv(path_to_data +  file_pret +'.csv', sep=';')
```

The output is:

```
       Categorie Offre           Categorie Pret          Date Creation  \
0           IMMOBILIER  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   2013-02-19 00:00:00   
1           IMMOBILIER  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2013-01-08 00:00:00   
2           IMMOBILIER  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2012-10-22 00:00:00   
3           IMMOBILIER  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2012-11-05 00:00:00   
4           IMMOBILIER  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    2013-08-06 00:00:00   
...                ...                      ...                    ...   
570435           AUTRE                      NaN  2021-04-01 00:00:00.0
```

I have a problem with this column  `info_prets['Nominal']`

```
0           190000
1           200000
2           190000

3           190000
4           200000
            ...   
570435     6000000
570436    11800000
570437     3000000
570438    13000000
570439      810000
```

when I convert this column to `float` as follows:

```
info_prets['Nominal']=info_prets['Nominal'].astype('float64')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '121651,05'
```

I tried to fix the problem by replacing commas with dots but the max number is clearly too low.

```
info_prets['Nominal']=info_prets['Nominal'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))

print(info_prets['Mt Nominal'].min())
print(info_prets['Mt Nominal'].max())

0
99999.98
```

I don't understand why is the max is low? something is wrong.  When checking the values of the column `info_prets['Nominal']` I have numbers much higher than that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `read_csv` can handle a different decimal separator from scratch: use `decimal=','` as parameter. In your example you still have strings and strings starting in `'9'` are sorted after those starting in`'1'` (`'9' > '11'`) you would need to convert with `pd.to_numeric`